What are colour ingredients in these biscuits?
In the attached picture you can see the ingredients for some ‘spicy ginger biscuits’ from costa.
I imagine the spicy flavour comes from the curcumin because I don’t see anything else that would get it as such.
Anyway the curcumin and Annato bixin is listed under colours.  What exactly does colours mean here?  To give colour to the biscuit but no flavouring, or both but it says colour because this was the main purpose. The biscuit itself looks like typical wheat(dark cream). Cant notice any extra colours.


Why wouldn't the spicy flavour be from the ginger?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annatto "Annato bixin" is a food dye.  They add it to the biscuit mix for the same reason that cheddar cheese makers add it to cheddar cheese in the US.

@Tetsujin I didn’t think ginger has such a strong spicy taste, however I’ve just realised stem ginger is a different product.  Is it because it’s stem ginger rather than ginger that it’s so spicy?  Thanks.

Both are spicy, though the flavour profiles are quite different.

You don't think that the final ingredient, ‘natural flavouring’, might be, well, flavouring it?  (Flavouring can be highly concentrated, so don't discount it because of the smaller mass.)  Though, as others have said, ginger can be pretty powerful, especially if you're only used to ground/powdered ginger (which is milder, sweeter, and used in smaller quantities).

Curcumin is the yellow compound found in turmeric.  Annato are seeds from the achiote tree.  Both are natural products used to color foods.  Color is generally added to foods to make them more appealing. (I agree with the comment above, the "spice" is likely from the ginger)

turmeric in large amounts can give a bit of a floral flavor to things, but I assume they're probably using it in an amount to get the sort of yellow that we often associate with 'buttery' in baked goods.
